# Add Text under Single Product Short Description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to add some Global Text immediately under the Product Short Description in Woo Commerce, before the product options.

I can change the file directly, but of course as soon as it updates it gets over written.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update 2:** There is 3 different ways, using hooks:

1) Adding your custom text at the end of the short description content, **(not for variable products**):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'add_text_after_excerpt_single_product', 20, 1 );
function add_text_after_excerpt_single_product( $post_excerpt ){
    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // Your custom text
    $post_excerpt .= '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
    <li>Current Delivery Times: Pink Equine - 4 - 6 Weeks, all other products 4 Weeks</li>
    </ul>';

    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

> **Important - For variable products:**
>   I found that there is bug like in When using the filter `woocommerce_short_description`that is apparently also **active for the product variation description, and it should not** *(as this is not documented in developers documentation)*… ***The solution is below:***

2) Adding your custom text at the end of the short description content, **for all product types**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
    global $product;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // The custom text
    $custom_text = '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
    <li>Current Delivery Times: Pink Equine - 4 - 6 Weeks, all other products 4 Weeks</li>
    </ul>';

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <?php echo $short_description . $custom_text; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

3) Adding your custom text after the short description:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'add_text_after_excerpt_single_product', 25 );
function add_text_after_excerpt_single_product(){
    global $product;

    // Output your custom text
    echo '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
    <li>Current Delivery Times: Pink Equine - 4 - 6 Weeks, all other products 4 Weeks</li>
    </ul>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I want to put it at the end of the short description content.  This is the text `code`<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
  <li>Current Delivery Times: Pink Equine - 4 - 6 Weeks, all other products 4 Weeks</li></ul>  `code`
  
 but on the function when I replace the custom text bit I get a parse error?  Can you help.

Comment: What it is I have a common UL LI and want to add a global one on the end, I have all the CSS set up so it works ok [link]http://www.pinkequine.com/pinknew/product/mattes-bespoke-ear-bonnets/ [link]

Comment: I have installed it and thought it worked ok, however when you add all the options in so that you can Add to Cart, the custom text appears 2 times see here [link]https://www.pinkequine.com/product/mattes-bespoke-long-stud-girth/ its weird because the ear bonnets works ok but this doesnt for some reason

Comment: maybe its something to do with the plugin I am using, it works fine initially but once all the options are selected I get a second copy come up in woocommerce-variation-description. I have accepted this as the answer as I think its the theme, but cant sort it out, thanks again

Comment: @DeniseField **Code Updated** - I just found that there is bug like in woocommerce with the filter `woocommerce_short_description`that is apparently active in the product variation description, and it should not… So I have found a turn around, **the 2nd way** freshly added… This will work for you as expected… So you can clean all old comments please as this is completely solved now.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you personally this solved the problem perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to sort this out, I wish I could upvote you even more than 1 point!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description','ts_add_text_short_descr');

function ts_add_text_short_descr($description){
    $text="Your text here";
    return $description.$text;
}
```