# Display category and brand name on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I am using [YITH WooCommerce Brands plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-brands-add-on/) to handle product brands.

I'm currently struggling with a fixed text That I want under my short description in WooCommerce. I want to display dynamically the **product name** in that text *(which works)*, but also the product category name `[CATEGORY_NAME]` and brand name `[BRAND_NAME]`.

But I can't seem to get those to work.

Based on this answer thread: [Add Text under Single Product Short Description in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577834/add-text-under-single-product-short-description-in-woocommerce/49578144#49578144)

Here is my code version:

```
// Add text after short description

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
    global $product;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // The custom text
    $custom_text = 'Zoekt u naast de '.$product->get_name().' andere [PRODUCT_CATEGORY] van dit merk? Bekijk dan eens de gehele collectie van [BRAND_NAME]. Powerlight is officieel dealer van [BRAND_NAME]. Heeft u een specifieke vraag over dit product? Neem gerust eens contact op met onze <span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a href="https://power-light.nl/contact/">klantenservice</a></span>. Onze adviseurs staan graag voor u klaar.';

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <?php echo $short_description . $custom_text; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Any idea's how I can display the product category name and the product brand name in my custom text?

Comment: Do you want to show the particular product's category? and what is Brand here?

Comment: `$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );` it will return you terms of that specific product then you have to just get its name

Comment: The brand is from the Yith brand plugin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will output you custom text just after the product short description with the correct Product category et the correct *(Yith)* product Brand *(So for YITH WooCommerce Brands plugin)*.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
    global $product;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // Get product categories
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    // Get product brands (NOTE: for Woocommerce brands plugin, the taxonomy is 'product_brand')
    $brands     = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'yith_product_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

    // The custom link
    $custom_link = '<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><a href="https://power-light.nl/contact/">'.__("klantenservice").'</a></span>';

    // The custom text
    $custom_text = sprintf(__("Zoekt u naast de %s andere %s van dit merk? Bekijk dan eens de gehele collectie van %s. Powerlight is officieel dealer van %s. Heeft u een specifieke vraag over dit product? Neem gerust eens contact op met onze %s. Onze adviseurs staan graag voor u klaar."), $product->get_name(), reset($categories), reset($brands), reset($brands), $custom_link );

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <?php echo $short_description . $custom_text; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

If you use **Woocommerce Brands plugin**, you will have to replace in the code `'yith_product_brand'` by `'product_brand'`. That's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot Loic! It works like a charm. I was wrong with the Yith plugin, i'm using the WC Brands plugin instead.