# Show brand tags in read more button on Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I am using [YITH WooCommerce Brands plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-brands-add-on/) to handle product brands. I would like to show brand tags in woocommerce read more button.

This is my code:

```
// Shop Catalog mode
if ( zget_option( 'woo_catalog_mode', 'zn_woocommerce_options', false, 'no' ) == 'yes' ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

    // Add the read more button
    // Fixes #917
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'zn_woocommerce_more_info' );
    function zn_woocommerce_more_info(){
        echo '<span class="kw-actions">';
            echo '<a class="actions-moreinfo" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'. __( "MORE INFO", 'zn_framework' ).'">';
            if ( zget_option( 'woo_prod_layout', 'zn_woocommerce_options', false, 'classic' ) == 'style2' ) {
                echo '<svg width="50px" height="24px" class="svg-moreIcon"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"/><circle cx="20" cy="12" r="2"/><circle cx="28" cy="12" r="2"/></svg>';
            } else {
                echo __( "MORE INFO", 'zn_framework' );
            }
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</span>';
    }
}
```

I need to replace the "read more" text with the specific brand of each product in woocommerce archive pages.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What plugin are you using for brands? Also your code has custom functions like zget_option() and zn_woocommerce_more_info() that nobody can guess and so your code is not testable…

Comment: I'm using YITH Brands Add-on

Answer (score 1):

To get the YITH brands tags for the current product in your hooked function, you will use:

```
// Get the YITH brands tags (array of term names)
$brands = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'yith_product_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

// Convert the array to a string (with coma separated brand tags)
$brands = implode(', ', $brands);
```

or if you have a unique brand set by product, you will use:

```
// Get the YITH brands tags (array of term names)
$brands = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'yith_product_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

// Convert the array to a string
$brand = reset($brands);
```

Now you can include easily this code in your hooked function to replace the "read more" text:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'zn_woocommerce_more_info' );
function zn_woocommerce_more_info(){
    echo '<span class="kw-actions">';
        $brands = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'yith_product_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        $brand = reset($brands);
        echo '<a class="actions-moreinfo" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'. $brand .'">';
        if ( zget_option( 'woo_prod_layout', 'zn_woocommerce_options', false, 'classic' ) == 'style2' ) {
            echo '<svg width="50px" height="24px" class="svg-moreIcon"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="2"/><circle cx="20" cy="12" r="2"/><circle cx="28" cy="12" r="2"/></svg>';
        } else {
            echo $brand;
        }
        echo '</a>';
    echo '</span>';
}
```

> If you use **Woocommerce Brands plugin**, you will have to replace in the code `'yith_product_brand'` by `'product_brand'`. That's all.

Related answer: [Display category and brand name on single product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325042/display-category-and-brand-name-on-single-product-page/51330185#51330185)