# Adding a custom text to woocommerce single products for a category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I Am using [Add Text under Single Product Short Description in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577834/add-text-under-single-product-short-description-in-woocommerce/49578144#49578144) 2nd code snippet on this answer.

I Changed a bit the following:

```
function custom_single_excerpt(){
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // The custom text
    $custom_text = 'custom text goes in here, custom text goes in here, custom text goes in here, custom text goes in here';

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
        <?php echo $short_description // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
        <div class="custom-text">
            <?php echo $custom_text; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I'd like to edit this to be able to just have it show on certain product categories if possible but not sure how.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: I did add my code, it seems ot have been stripped away now?

Comment: I have answered. Some feed back on the answer below is gratefully appreciated please.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `has_term()` WordPress conditional function to target specific product categories:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
    global $product;

    // Here set your product category terms Ids, slugs or names.
    $categories = array( 'toons', 'dolls' );

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

For multiple different texts by category, you will use instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
    global $product;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
    global $post, $product;

    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // For "toons" category
    if ( has_term( array('toons'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $custom_text = __('A custom text for "Toons" category');
    } 
    // For "people" category
    elseif ( has_term( array('people'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $custom_text = __('A different custom text for "People" category');
    } 
    // For All other categories (or no categories)
    else {
        $custom_text = __('A custom text for All other categories (or no categories)');
    }
 
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">' . 
        $short_description // WPCS: XSS ok.
        . '<div class="custom-text">' . $custom_text // WPCS: XSS ok.
        . '</div>
    </div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.