# WooCommerce | Add custom text at the end of the short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I put the following code at the end of my short product description? (WooCommerce)

```
<tbody class="table-hover">
    <?php if ( get_field( 'platform' ) ): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left prd-platform ">Platform:</td>
            <td class="text-left trd-platform">
            <?php $terms = get_field('platform');
    if( $terms ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
            <a class="acflinkcls" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want this code to be part of my short product description 
Thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, you have two alternatives:

1: edit your `theme_name/woocommerce` or use `child_theme`. (Personally I prefer to use a child theme as a solution.)

2: you may use `woocommerce_short_description` to add your code.

3: add the following code in `functions.php` of your theme. you will see `functions.php` in the following path: `wp-content/teme_name/functions.php`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sally_below_single_product_summary', 20 );
function sally_below_single_product_summary() {
?>
<tbody class="table-hover">
    <?php if ( get_field( 'platform' ) ): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-left prd-platform ">Platform:</td>
            <td class="text-left trd-platform">
            <?php $terms = get_field('platform');
    if( $terms ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
            <a class="acflinkcls" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>  

<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding your custom text at the end of the short description content, (**not for variable products**):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'add_text_after_excerpt_single_product', 20, 1 );
function add_text_after_excerpt_single_product( $post_excerpt ){
    if ( ! $short_description )
        return;

    // Your custom text
    $post_excerpt .= '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
    <li>Current Delivery Times: Pink Equine - 4 - 6 Weeks, all other products 4 Weeks</li>
    </ul>';

    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Follow the URL below to resolve your issue:

[Add Text under Single Product Short Description in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577834/add-text-under-single-product-short-description-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks
But the code you gave can only contain HTML
I want it to accept PHP code as well, just like the code I provided