Adding custom text under specific product pages in specific categories Woocommerce
How to add some custom text line under specific product pages after short description in specific categories Woocommerce?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577834/add-text-under-single-product-short-description-in-woocommerce add the necessary conditions to restrict it per product id or category
